# python : pandas install errors on container

Tags: python, pandas

I want to install `pandas` on docker image containing python. I used the code below to run a container:

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -v  /home/DATA/Project_NY/:/home/jovyan/work/Project_NY jupyter/scipy-notebook
```

I created a new notebook and then tried to install my requirements file doing `pip install -r "requirements.txt"` i got the error below and when I tried to `pip install pandas` inside that running container it works perfectly:
**requirements.txt content**

```
SQLAlchemy==1.2.2
pandas==0.25.0
docker==3.3.0
python-json-logger
sshtunnel==0.1.4
jupyter
jupytext==0.8.4
matplotlib
seaborn
psycopg2-binary
```

**the error is**

```
  building 'pandas._libs.algos' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/pandas
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/pandas/_libs
  gcc -pthread -B /opt/conda/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/conda/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/conda/include -fPIC -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -I./pandas/_libs -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/opt/conda/include/python3.9 -c pandas/_libs/algos.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/pandas/_libs/algos.o -Wno-unused-function
  error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the pandas version you are trying to install needs a custom build for the System you're using as Dockercontainer.

You should get the same error if you run `pip install pandas==0.25.0` inside the container.

Either use a different version of pandas or install gcc in the container ( e.g.: for alpine, inside Dockerfile `CMD apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc`).

EDIT: I think the 'jupyter/scipy-notebook'-image uses conda, so maybe try:

`docker run -p 8888:8888 -v  /home/DATA/Project_NY/:/home/jovyan/work/Project_NY jupyter/scipy-notebook conda install gcc`

the `conda install gcc` in the end is executed inside the container.

Comment: thank you for your response, im not using alpine ! i pull this image jupyter/scipy-notebook

Comment: i have now dockerfile the only command i did is docker run -p 8888:8888 -v  /home/DATA/Project_NY/:/home/jovyan/work/Project_NY jupyter/scipy-notebook

Comment: I've edited my answer, I would suggest using a Dockerfile regardless, also I would suggest to just use a different pandas version if possible.

Comment: got this error Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Comment: you can as well suggest me an other image if you know well ! Thank you